# Is the authentication method using saml going to be deprecated

Tags: authentication

We are considering how to correctly authenticate our application with Sharepoint.

The simplest option seems to be by getting a SAML token, as it just requires a username and password and there are no need for add-ins

However we have noticed that there is a SOAP request as part of this procedure and we have read that the SOAP services are being deprecated.

Is it unwise for us to choose this method of authentication for our application for this reason

Answer (score 1):

For SharePoint Server, no SAML won't be deprecated any time soon and it would only be deprecated in a vNext build of Server. Deprecation of authentication protocols would likely mean notification of that deprecation in a vNext build with a removal in vNext-Next :-)

I wouldn't be concerned with it.